# Выборка событий по дате.

Tags: mysql

Существует таблица с некоторыми событиями, имеющая структуру:

`id,name,date`, события имеют годовую периодичность (как праздники). Необходимо выбрать события таким образом, чтобы выводились ближайшие пять, если к примеру в один день 10 событий, то при каждом запросе выдавало пять рандомных.

**Решено:**

```
   select * from table where date>=CURRENT_DATE order by date,rand()limit 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плюс `order by rand()` под конец и лимит 5.

Comment: В этом случае, он перемешает все записи которые старше текущего дня и в итоге мы не получим ближайшие.

Comment: Ок, а если попробовать с join, например, такое:

    select id,name,date,
    from table t1
    join(
    select id,name,date 
    from table
    where date>CURRENT_DATE
    order by date
    limit 5
    ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    order by rand();

Comment: В этом случае, запрос, выберет 5 ближайших и потом будет их сортировать в итоге будут выводится теже самые элементы только в рандомном порядке.

Comment: Тогда вопрос в другом. Какой порог времени на количество событий?
т.е. в первый день 4 события, а во второй день 15 событий, запрос должен выводить все 4 события 1-го дня и рандомно одно событие второго дня? Или рандомно 5 событий от этих двух дней?

Comment: 4 события первого дня и рандомно 1 событие второго дня.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно достать записи, дата которых превышает текущую - это и будут ближайшие